# Hook on mscorlib (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream) to log parameters

Tags: .net, hook, intercept, method-call

I want to log the parameters which are given to a CryptoStream object in an application, to log the plaintext before it is encrypted.

I want to do this dynamically, without tampering with the original file. Is there a way to create a "layer" between the app and the framework to intercept the desired function calls, write the desired parameter to a text file, and then pass control back to the framework?

If yes, could you point me in the right direction, and give a sample?

And for those who have legal concerns about this (this sounds like a s/w cracking question, I know ;) ) :
I have the permission of the developer to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it either writing a specific **debugger** or a specific **profiler**. Here is a link to the [CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2282) and a link to the [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4 (sources and binaries)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this without tampling the original file:
1.Using the SSCLI, use clix.exe to start your application and set break points in CLR source code.
2.Using Windbg+SOS.dll and load the symbols from MS, set breakpoints before the method entry.
3.the third way is new in blackhat converence. modify the system.*.dll of MS. make it to MSIL and add some IL in the Crypto method. and build it back to dll and make the application use it.